# Replace RichTextBox Text but keep formatting

Tags: wpf, replace, richtextbox

Can anybody cast some light on this for me, I have a RichTextBox which im loading an xaml file into it. I need to Replace certain Parts of the RichTxtBox's text with real data i.e. '[our_name]' is replaced with 'Billie Brags'. My xaml file contains formatting like bold & font size.

When I run my code (shown below) I can change the text OK but im loosing the formatting.

Any idea how I can do this and keep the formatting?

Thank you

```
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            using (fs)
            {
                TextRange RTBText = new TextRange(rtb_wording.Document.ContentStart, rtb_wording.Document.ContentEnd);
                RTBText.Load(fs, DataFormats.Xaml);
            }



        TextRange tr = new TextRange(rtb_wording.Document.ContentStart, rtb_wording.Document.ContentEnd);
        string rtbContent = tr.Text;
        rtbContent = rtbContent.Replace("<our_name>", "Billie Brags");
        System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(rtbContent);

        FlowDocument myFlowDoc = new FlowDocument();

        // Add paragraphs to the FlowDocument
        myFlowDoc.Blocks.Add(new Paragraph(new Run(rtbContent)));
        rtb_wording.Document = myFlowDoc;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Its working, this is how I did it in the end, not too pretty but it functions. WPF RTB really should have rtf property like winforms...

Thanks to Kent for putting me on the right track.

```
            var textRange = new TextRange(rtb_wording.Document.ContentStart, rtb_wording.Document.ContentEnd);
            string rtf;
            using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                textRange.Save(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
                rtf = ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray());
            }

            rtf = rtf.Replace("<our_name>", "Bob Cratchet");

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(ASCIIEncoding.Default.GetBytes(rtf));
            rtb_wording.SelectAll();
            rtb_wording.Selection.Load(stream, DataFormats.Rtf);
```

Comment: Also you may want to use 'UTF32Encoding.Default.GetString(memoryStream.ToArray()); this is better suited for globalized applications

Answer (score 1):

I believe you'll need to save the contents of the `TextRange` in RTF format, and then reload the contents of the RTB. I haven't tried this so not sure it will work (on linux at the moment so can't test):

```
var textRange = new TextRange(rtb.Document.ContentStart, rtb.Document.ContentEnd);
string rtf;

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
{
    textRange.Save(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
    rtf = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}

rtf = rtf.Replace("<whatever>", "whatever else");

using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(rtf)))
{
    textRange.Load(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);
}
```

Comment: Are you using the RichTextBox from the toolkit? Because the one in WPF 4 does not have such a property...

Comment: My bad - was thinking of Winforms RTB.

Comment: Hi Kent, thanks for that but im getting an error - 'Unrecognized structure in data format 'Rich Text Format'.
Parameter name: stream'. I have changed my code to save file in rtf and not xaml now but still get the error.

Comment: Sorry, error occurs at : textRange.Load(memoryStream, DataFormats.Rtf);